# Rails template for dynamically routed static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, routes

I'm having my Rails application search the pages folder and create routes for each and generating methods for them within the controller.  The code works great!  But I can't get the template file to load with the page rendered within it.  Here's my code:

#### `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  attr_reader :pages_list

  def initialize
    PagesController.pages_list.each {|name|
      define_singleton_method(name) {}
    }
  end

  def self.pages_list
    Dir.glob(
        Rails.root + "app/views/pages/*"
    ).select {|f|
      File.file? f
    }.map {|f|
      File.basename(f)[0..File.basename(f).index(".").to_i-1]
    }.uniq
  end
end
```

#### `config/routes.rb`

```
PagesController.pages_list.each do |page|
  get "/#{page}", to: "pages##{page}", as: "#{page}_page"
end
```

And I'm very happy to have working routing with URL helpers for any page I drop in.  But the template isn't showing from `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

I've tried the following in **PagesController**:

```
include HighVoltage::StaticPage

layout :application

def initialize
  PagesController.pages_list.each {|name|
    define_singleton_method(name) {render layout: "application"}
  }
end
```

But this does nothing to the pages.  Help is appreciated!

---

The views are the generic boiler plates:

**`app/views/pages/contact.html.erb`**

```
<% content_for :title do %>Contact<% end %>
<h3>Contact info for the website</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

**`app/views/pages/about.html.erb`**

```
<% content_for :title do %>About<% end %>
<h3>About the website</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

Comment: After looking around I've found this approach to be more to my liking http://archive.gibberishcode.net/archives/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4/130 .  I will leave this question here in case some one can get it to render the application template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you don't need to have each method defined within the controller to do this.  It works by removing my initialize method from my example and adding a layout option.

#### `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  attr_reader :pages_list
  layout "my_custom_layout"

  def self.pages_list
    Dir.glob(
        Rails.root + "app/views/pages/*"
    ).select {|f|
      File.file? f
    }.map {|f|
      File.basename(f)[0..File.basename(f).index(".").to_i-1]
    }.uniq
  end
end
```

#### `config/routes.rb`

```
PagesController.pages_list.each do |page|
  get "/#{page}", to: "pages##{page}", as: "#{page}_page"
end
```

The right view file gets called even with no method of the same name defined in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be simpler, instead of creating actions for each view separately, hove one action for all of them?

routes:

```
get '/:page', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
```

controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    render params[:page], layout: 'application'
  rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
    raise ActionController::RoutingError, 'Not Found'
  end

end
```

Ant that's should be it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't provide any url helpers for static pages such as contact_page_path and about_page_path

Comment: @6ftDan - updated, now you can do `page_path(:my_page)`

Comment: The `rake routes` command brings up ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'page'.  This is just from `get '/:page', to: 'pages#show', as: :page`

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing the rest of your routes. `:static_page` then?

Comment: Change your render line to this `render params[:page], layout: "application"` and it works.

Comment: `render params[:page]` is rendering the the template. If you prefer your helpers then you probably need to stick with what you have, I can only say I don't like this approach - Hard to tell why though, maybe its the necessity to restart the server every time you add new file, misleading error message given to your co-workers when they remove the template. My approach has some issues as well, so I think it is matter of personal preference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59439/discussion-between-broisatse-and-6ft-dan).

Comment: Hmm, I would expect it will use application layout by default. Need to check that.

Comment: This is the way I'd do it - DRY

Comment: @BroiSatse I'm leaning towards doing this, but it feels a little dirty. Are there any security concerns with passing a param into a render function like this?